# Why is Internet Explorer the only browser that can open .url links by default?

Tags: windows, windows-10, browser, default-settings

Why is Internet Explorer the only browser that can open `.url` links by default?
I have tried setting Chrome, Firefox and Edge to be the default browser but none of them have this open `.urls` by default option.

**Side note-** I was able to set Firefox to the default for opening .url files by  going to the file associations link in the control panel rather than the default program link. (Default Programs\Set Associations)  So if Firefox can do it, why isn't this option available as a default association?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, you may just have to hunt down the `.exe` of the browser you wish.

**Example:**

Chrome's `.exe` is usually stored at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application`

So when you go to choose a default application, go ahead and hit browse and direct it to Chrome's executable inside that directory.

[image]

You can do the same with other browsers as well, just gotta hunt down the `.exe` that runs the browser.

---

## Extra note

As of now, you have the default set as *"Internet Browser"* which means whatever browser your computer considers your "default" is the one that will open `.url` shortcuts.  Which is probably Internet Explorer at the moment from what it seems.

Comment: Oooh. Thanks for the extra note. I didn't notice that. Thank you.